# Определение IP адресов

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой - как можно узнать IP адреса, которые обращались к определённому адресу?

Comment: на "определённом адресе" повешать "писателя" истории обращений к нему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "определенный адрес" - это ваш сервер, то

```
public static String GetIP()
{
    String ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return ip;
}
```